# Which trigonometric formula(s) are required to find values of quantities?

Tags: trigonometry

I have read the relevant chapter in my calculus book (Calculus: A Complete Course) and I can not figure out how to solve the first problem:

**"Find the values of the quantities [...] using various formulas [...] Do not use tables or a calculator.**

**1.**  cos$(\frac{3\pi}{4})$

I have tried using several formulas, and I can not find a way to solve it. The subsequent problems are variants of the one above and use **tan** and **sin** instead of **cos**.

Which trigonometric formula(s) am I supposed to use and how?

Comment: **Hint.** $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) = \cos\left(\pi - \frac{\pi}{4}\right).$ From here, you should be able to transform this into an easy to calculate cosine.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4})=\cos(\pi-\frac{\pi}{4})=-\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Using
$$\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos(\alpha)$$

If you don't remember that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, you can use the fact that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and get $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})$. Then you can plug this into $\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)=1$ to obtain:
$$\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4})+\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4})=1 \implies \cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{2} \implies \cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$